# Setting a value of an array not working - why?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to declare an integer array in android studio / java. When I try to set a value of this array, android studio does not recognize it.

I have tried using String instead of int and other types of arrays but I still get the same result.

```
int[] hello = new int[5];
hello[0] = 1;
```

The second statement is underlined in Android Studio and hovering over it displays different kinds of errors which means it does not recognize the statement. If I move my pointer over hello I get "unknown class: hello". If I move it over other parts of the statement I get "Identifier expected" and "unexpected token".

Edit: I had the semicolon in my original code, I just didn't paste it correctly. As for the whole class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int hello[] = new int[5];
    hello[1] = 2;
    TextView texty;
    String s = String.valueOf(hello[1]);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("mainy", s);
    }

    TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView t2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView t3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView t4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView t5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    public void nextPage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String s = data.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.KEY);
                texty.setText(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you check if AS recognizes it ?

Comment: judging by the three different errors it doesn't seem like AS is really identifying an error, rather than not recognizing the statement at all.

Comment: add a semi-colon `int[] hello = new int[5]; // <-- here`

Comment: Declare Array at class level `int[] hello = new int[5];` and  then use `hello[0] = 1;` line inside any method

Comment: Can you show the entire class causing trouble ?

Comment: just added the whole class and corrected my typo

Comment: in the class scope you can only declare members, you can't run any logic, you should init as inline initialization with values or do it in the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually basic knowledge about Java you lack and this question shouldn't be on stackoverflow. You can't implement logic outside methods. You may only declare variables.

What you should do looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int hello[];
    TextView texty;
    String s;

    void method(){
        hello = new int[5];
        hello[1] = 2;
        s = String.valueOf(hello[1])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got confused having recently moved to android and being used to writing java in the main method I was surprised that it didn't work in the class, hence the question.

Comment: Still, this is basic knowledge you get from any tutorial or book you just lack, I suggest you learn Java a bit more before making android apps (which is really bad "place" to start learning language)